# Using audit tables instead of transactions advisable?

Tags: sql-server, winforms, transactions, audit

I am working on a project where Winforms/WebAPI/SqlServer stack. Currently there is no transaction support in the API.  If I need to make several post/ delete calls (which would be a part of a transaction) to the API, I have no control over rolling it back in case if there is a failure somewhere. Currently, working around this by keeping track of the inserted/deleted rows in the client side and perform reverse calls in case of failures.

I am implementing transactions in the controller/DAL layer. Architect of the team is suggesting that we don't need transaction support and we should be able to use Audit tables to recover from failures to put the data back to the previous state.  Is it recommended?

Comment: Audit tables as in keeping track of what a table looked like at a certain point in time? That's a possible solution if your only goal is to essentially 'roll back' the tables to that point in time... But for more complex things (like, say, you need to insert into 3 tables successfully but the 3rd insert fails), I'm not sure how an audit log would help. So it really depends on what your needs are and how complex your tables/queries are, I suppose.

Comment: We do multiple inserts/updates on several tables for the transaction. No complex queries.